# What does "this" mean in a static method declaration?

Tags: c#, .net, syntax, methods, extension-methods

I've seen some code that uses the keyword `this` in the function parameter declaration. For example:

```
public static Object SomeMethod( this Object blah, bool blahblah)
```

What does the word `this` mean in that context?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It means `SomeMethod()` is an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) to the `Object` class.

After defining it you can call this method on any `Object` instances (despite it being declared `static`), like so:

```
object o = new Object();
bool someBool = true;

// Some other code...

object p = o.SomeMethod(someBool);
```

The `this Object` parameter refers to the object you call it on, and is not actually found in the parameter list.

The reason why it's declared `static` while you call it like an instance method is because the compiler translates that to a real static call in the IL. That goes deep down though, so I shan't elaborate, but it also means you can call it as if it were any static method:

```
object o = new Object();
bool someBool = true;

// ...

object p = ObjectExtensions.SomeMethod(o, someBool);
```

Answer (score 2):

It is how you declare an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).

This means that you can invoke SomeMethod with `.SomeMethod` for any object. The object before the `.` will be the blah parameter.

```
string s = "sdfsd";
Object result = s.SomeMethod(false);
```

The extension method will be available on all types inheriting from the type of the `this` parameter, in this case object. If you have `SomeMethod(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable)` it will be available on all `IEnumerable<T>`:s like `List<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

Extension method:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx